# How do you keep the autocomplete text box in JetBrains Rider or other Intellij IDEs from obscuring surrounding text?

Tags: intellij-idea, resharper, jetbrains-rider

As I'm typing in JetBrains Rider, the autocomplete textbox(s) will immediately appear over and under what I'm typing, which obscures the surrounding detail of the code that I'm writing.  Often times I need to be able to see that code and I'm uninterested in the autocomplete suggestions.  This results in a lot of pressing the 'Esc' key to hide the text (which is a very awkward button to type quickly and greatly interrupts my train of thought as I'm typing).

I can't believe that I'm the only person to be mildly annoyed by this behavior of IDEs, but I haven't been able to find any suggestions on how to deal with it, or what to google for settings to tweak it.  Maybe there's a setting to just delay the popup window for a half second?  I'd also just like to hear other programmers thoughts on the IDE settings they use to configure code completion to optimize it for productivity and minimize annoyances?

And as I'm sure that other people have the same questions about Visual Studio / VSCode and IntelliSense, feel free to address those settings as well, along with IntelliJ IDEA and Resharper.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Visual Studio (with ReSharper), you could hold the ctrl to make the code completion popup transparent. See detailed steps here: https://irishdotnet.dev/make-intellisense-transparent-while-typing-in-visual-studio

If you are using VSCode, you could configure the `editorSuggestWidget.background` setting to make the code completion dialog transparent. See here for details: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/22439#issuecomment-600855615

Unfortunately, JetBrains Rider or other IntelliJ IDEs don't support this feature. Please vote for the related feature request here: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-126993/
As a workaround, you could the disable automatic code completion popup `File | Settings | Editor | General | Code Completion -> Show suggestions as you type` and call completion explicitly via `Ctrl+Space`.